# How to install library libgvfscommon on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 14.04

While using ./configure for "Synce " I am getting error

```
configure: error: Required library libgvfscommon not found
```

I tried to search for libgvfscommon , but couldnot find it . How to install it  ?

Answer (score 2):

From http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libgvfscommon.so, you need to install the `gvfs-libs` package:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gvfs-libs
```

Comment: gvfs-libs is already installed . But still it is throwing the same error  .

Comment: @AtifImam Where did you get the installation instructions for synce? I would like to take a look.

Comment: This is the link from where I downloaded Synce . It has a readme file with instruction for installation . https://sourceforge.net/projects/synce/?source=typ_redirect

Comment: . Did you get the link ?

Comment: @AtifImam Yes I did. I will look through it later.

Comment: @SuB . yes sure , if I will get a working solution  .

Comment: @AtifImam I am getting the same error as you did, but I am not sure how to fix it yet. Meanwhile, I found a PPA for SynCE at https://launchpad.net/~synce/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+index?field.series_filter=xenial. You can consider using that PPA so you don't have to install from source.